# OpenGL, diffuse shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to implement very simple diffuse shader in GLSL/openGL.
Here's what I got:
Vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 vertPos3D;
in vec3 vertNormal3D;

uniform mat3 transpMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;

varying vec3 vertNormal;
varying vec3 lightVector;

void main() 
{ 
    vec4 res_pos = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(vertPos3D.xyz, 1.0);
    gl_Position = res_pos;
    mat4 pm = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix;
    vertNormal = (viewMatrix * vec4(vertNormal3D, 0)).xyz;
    lightVector = (viewMatrix * vec4(lightPosition, 1.0)).xyz - (viewMatrix * vec4(vertPos3D.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 130
out vec4 color; 

varying vec3 lightVector;
varying vec3 vertNormal;
void main()
{
    float dot_product = max(normalize(dot(lightVector, vertNormal)), 0.0);
    color = dot_product * vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}
```

As soon as I multiply final color with dot_product, nothing displays. I remove dot_product, everything works (except diffuse lightning ofc.). I'm afraid it's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Anything in the shader compilation/link logs?

Answer (score 4):

**A problem:**

```
normalize(dot(lightVector, vertNormal))
```

`dot` in GLSL 1.3 returns a float.
`normalize` accepts a vector, not a float.
[documentation for dot](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/dot.xml)
[documentation for normalize](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/normalize.xml)

**A Solution, at least to this problem:**

In Fragment shader, replace

```
float dot_product = max(normalize(dot(lightVector, vertNormal)), 0.0);
```

with

```
float dot_product = clamp(dot(lightVector, vertNormal), 0., 1.);
```

It looks like you are using max and normalize to avoid negative numbers returned from `dot`. This is exactly what `clamp` is for. Here's the [documentation for clamp](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/clamp.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I changed that line of code, but overall nothing has changed. :(

Comment: Oh, wait your using GLSL 1.3, so try switching `in` with `attribute` in your vertex shader and in the fragment shader removing `out vec4 color;` and replacing `color` with `gl_FragColor`

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: Ok, the `varying` in the fragment shader should be `attribute` because it's input not output. I edited the code above. Does it work now?

Comment: @DylanHolmes *"Ok, the varying in the fragment shader should be attribute because it's input not output. "* - No, it shouldn't, since it's, well, a varying and not a vertex attribute.

Comment: Actually 1.30 already has `in/out`, so drop all this deprecated `attribute/varying` rubbish anyway.

Comment: I've replaced varying with in/out, doesn't help tho...it seems that dot product in fragment shader is always zero. Are calculations inside vertex shader correct?

Comment: @user1760770 if you want to check your vectors just print them out. So you see if they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`float dot_product = max(dot(normalize(lightVector), normalize(normalVector)), 0.0);`

Dylan Holmes answer is slightly incorrect:

Still the lightVector needs to be normalized!

And clamping is unnecessary. `max` was correct. A dot product never returns a value higher then 1.0 if input vectors are normalized.

Comment: To be precise: 'A dot product never returns a value higher then 1.0' only true if vectors was normalized, and vertNormal still needs to be normalized because it's interpolated value, not application-presented normal.

Comment: Before your comment i added this info to the answer about the dot product. Shader programming is some years ago for me, so i wasn't sure if it is necessary.

Comment: @djmj normalizing did slip my mind, and thanks for pointing that out about clamp/max.